# Developing C++ applications to run on embedded Linux setup

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, glibc

I am required to write a C++ application to run on an embedded Linux setup (DMP Vortex86DX processor). The vendor provides a [minimal linux installation image](http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/) that can be installed to the board and contains appropriate hardware drivers. My question is motivated by the answer to my previous question about writing Linux software on a [particular kernel to run on a different kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014215/will-a-c-linux-app-built-on-version-x-xx-of-the-kernel-run-on-an-earlier-versi) . I don't really know where to start when it comes to writing the software with regards to ensuring compatibility.

My instinctive approach would be to install the same versions of g++ on the embedded device and on my desktop development machine, write the application on the dev maching, copy to the board and compile it there. This seems madness though and I find it hard to believe that this is how embedded software is developed. With regards to the answer to my previous question, is there a way I can simply build on my desktop but use the version of glibc that exists on the embedded device - if so how can enforce linkage to a specific version? Or is it possible to build everything statically so that the application doesn't link to anything dynamically (I doubt this is possible).

I am a total novice to embedded development, and foresee months of frustration unless I can get hold of some good advice or resources. Any pointers or suggestion of where to start will be very gratefully received no matter how simple or trivial they seem - I really am starting at the very bottom with regards to embedded stuff.

Comment: Ahm.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler

Comment: And to quote your customer support: `We offer free software support resource for your reference only. Our resource might lead you to other websites. It is to save your research time and we don't have any obligation or responsibility to provide further support or answer questions on your application. If you need any special assistance, please contact your account manager.`

Comment: @Bo Thanks for your first link - at least the part after the ellpisis.

Comment: Look... I just checkedout the docs from the link you provided and they clearly specify: `8.14.  Develop Application
X-Linux is a run-time environment for developers and does not provide tool-chain. Developers have to make their programs on desktop PC and put them onto X-Linux to run. Refer to below section for more.`. To be honest to you this I hate to see.  But still contact them and ask them for suggestions, they might be able to make your life much much easier

Comment: @Bo I have tried this and got nowhere fast. Spend weeks getting ubuntu installed (just installed) despite them saying it is supported. I am getting nowhere and my hands are tied as it is work related and this is what I have to work with. Hence the plea for assistance (any assistance) here.

Comment: Hi again! Sad that this board is still causing you trouble. As @Bo said above, you need to cross compile from your desktop computer. The only thing is, you have to find out the processor architecture. Then you cross your fingers that GCC supports it.

Comment: Thanks - even stuff like "cross-compile" is totally new to me. With any luck my company will either change hardware, get an embedded linux guy in or sack me. I am not fussy about which one right now.

Comment: @mathematician1975: Checkout other forums on the web that have posts already on topic of DMP Vortex86DX (better to look for specific board you are using) and you might stumble upon person who has dealt with your board.

Comment: @Bo Yeah I have been doing this but I will keep on trying. Thanks for your suggestions anyway - at least I have a starting point now

Comment: Did you contact Netcom guys? They stated in their brochure ( "http://www.netcomipc.com.tw/catalog/images/NC-499%20catalog.pdf?osCsid=405ee8422bc34f3b9f45104e219bf579":   **OS support: Windows XPe, WinCE, Linux, DOS**

Comment: Indirectly yes. I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: Good luck.  Keep in mind that most of people who write software with boards are not experienced and and are not capable to setup toolchain on their own.  That is why most manufacturers provide tools for their boards. Not all but most.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and pointers here. I am (finally) making some progress and have some idea on where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, given the fact that the [Vortex86SX/DX/MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex86) claims to be x86 compatible, a small set of compiler switches should enable you to compile code for your target machine: `-m32` to ensure 32bit code, and no `-march` switch targeting a specific CPU.

Then you'll need to link your code. As long as you don't use anything fancy, but simple established glibc functions, I'd expect the ABI to be the same on your development machine and the embedded system. In other words, you compile against your host libraries, copy the binary to the embedded system, and it should simply run using the libraries available there.

If X-Linux were to use some other libc, like [uclibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) or similar, then you'd need a cross compiler on your host. I have little experience with Ubuntu in that regard, but I know that the `sys-devel/crossdev` package for Gentoo linux makes generation of cross-compilers very easy. This can be both for different architectures (not needed in your case) and different libraries (like e.g. uclibc).

I'd say simply give copying the binaries a try, and report back if you encounter any problems there.

Comment: Many thanks for this - I will give this a try. According to their info the current version uses glibc 2.8.90

Comment: Managed to get this Xlinux installed finally so now at least I have a starting point (which is what I wanted) so thanks very much for the help